# Exception - Attribute is specified with no value: url

Tags: javascript, exception, google-apps-script

The second call `fetch` throw exception because it loses value of `url`. Why?

See stack trace. Twice error 429 and call `onRetryAfter` for each. But exception only for the second. The first `fetch` has `url`, the second loses it.

```
Exception: Attribute is specified with no value: url
    at fetch(Library:38:41)
    at onRetryAfter(Library:84:20)
    at onError(Library:109:24)
    at readResponse(Library:78:16)
    at fetch(Library:38:16)
    at onRetryAfter(Library:84:20)
    at onError(Library:109:24)
    at readResponse(Library:78:16)
    at [unknown function](Library:63:24)
    at fetchAll(Library:62:43)
```

### Log

```
// error
URL: https://api.spotify.com/v1/search/?q=x%20ambassadors%20unsteady&type=track&limit=1 
Code: 429 
Params: { headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ***' },
  payload: undefined,
  muteHttpExceptions: true } 
Content: {
  "error": {
    "status": 429,
    "message": "API rate limit exceeded"
  }
}

// info with url
https://api.spotify.com/v1/search/?q=x%20ambassadors%20unsteady&type=track&limit=1 { headers: { Authorization: 'Bearer ***' },
  payload: undefined,
  muteHttpExceptions: true }

// Error
URL: undefined 
Code: 429 
Params: {} 
Content: {
  "error": {
    "status": 429,
    "message": "API rate limit exceeded"
  }
}

// Info without url
undefined { muteHttpExceptions: true }
```

### Calling

Call `fetchAll` into `SpotifyRequest.getAll`

```
    function multisearchTracks(textArray) {
        return SpotifyRequest.getAll(
            textArray.map((text) =>
                Utilities.formatString(
                    '%s/search/?%s',
                    API_BASE_URL,
                    CustomUrlFetchApp.parseQuery({
                        q: text,
                        type: 'track',
                        limit: '1',
                    })
                )
            )
        ).map((response) => response && response.items ? response.items[0] : {});
    }

const SpotifyRequest = (function () {
    return {
        getAll: getAll,
    };


    function getAll(urls) {
        let requests = [];
        urls.forEach((url) =>
            requests.push({
                url: url,
                headers: getHeaders(),
                method: 'get',
            })
        );
        return CustomUrlFetchApp.fetchAll(requests).map((response) => extractContent(response));
    }

    function extractContent(response) {
        if (!response) return;
        let keys = Object.keys(response);
        if (keys.length == 1 && !response.items) {
            response = response[keys[0]];
        }
        return response;
    }

    function getHeaders() {
        return {
            Authorization: 'Bearer ' + Auth.getAccessToken(),
        };
    }
})();
```

### Full code

```js
const CustomUrlFetchApp = (function () {
    let countRequest = 0;
    return {
        fetch: fetch,
        fetchAll: fetchAll,
        parseQuery: parseQuery,
        getCountRequest: () => countRequest,
    };

    function fetch(url, params = {}) {
        countRequest++;
        params.muteHttpExceptions = true;
        return readResponse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params));
    }

    function fetchAll(requests) {
        countRequest += requests.length;
        requests.forEach((request) => (request.muteHttpExceptions = true));
        let responseArray = [];
        let limit = 30;
        let count = Math.ceil(requests.length / limit);
        for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            const requestPack = requests.splice(0, limit);
            const responseRaw = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(requestPack);
            const responses = responseRaw.map((response, index) => {
                return readResponse(response, requestPack[index].url, {
                    headers: requestPack[index].headers,
                    payload: requestPack[index].payload,
                    muteHttpExceptions: requestPack[index].muteHttpExceptions,
                });
            });
            Combiner.push(responseArray, responses);
        }
        return responseArray;
    }

    function readResponse(response, url, params = {}) {
        if (isSuccess(response.getResponseCode())) {
            return onSuccess();
        }
        return onError();

        function onRetryAfter() {
            let value = response.getHeaders()['Retry-After'] || 2;
            console.error('Ошибка 429. Пауза', value);
            Utilities.sleep(value > 60 ? value : value * 1000);
            return fetch(url, params);
        }

        function tryFetchOnce() {
            Utilities.sleep(3000);
            countRequest++;
            response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
            if (isSuccess(response.getResponseCode())) {
                return onSuccess();
            }
            writeErrorLog();
        }

        function onSuccess() {
            let type = response.getHeaders()['Content-Type'] || '';
            if (type.includes('json')) {
                return parseJSON(response);
            }
            return response;
        }

        function onError() {
            writeErrorLog();
            let responseCode = response.getResponseCode();
            if (responseCode == 429) {
                return onRetryAfter();
            } else if (responseCode >= 500) {
                return tryFetchOnce();
            }
        }

        function isSuccess(code) {
            return code >= 200 && code < 300;
        }

        function writeErrorLog() {
            console.error('URL:', url, '\nCode:', response.getResponseCode(), '\nParams:', params, '\nContent:', response.getContentText());
        }
    }

    function parseJSON(response) {
        let content = response.getContentText();
        return content.length > 0 ? tryParseJSON(content) : { msg: 'Пустое тело ответа', status: response.getResponseCode() };
    }

    function tryParseJSON(content) {
        try {
            return JSON.parse(content);
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e, e.stack, content);
            return [];
        }
    }

    function parseQuery(obj) {
        return Object.keys(obj)
            .map((k) => `${encodeURIComponent(k)}=${encodeURIComponent(obj[k])}`)
            .join('&');
    }
})();
```

Comment: Where is your calling code?

Comment: @TheMaster `fetchAll` calling from `getAll`

Comment: Ok. What do you mean by "The second call"? Could you provide a repro? [Mcve]

Comment: @TheMaster see stack trace. Twice error 429 and call `onRetryAfter` for each. But exception only for the second. The first `fetch` has `url`, the second loses it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Issue:

```
function readResponse(response, url, params = {}) {
  /*stuff*/
}

/*...*/
function fetch(url, params = {}) {
    /*...*/
    return readResponse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params));
}
```

`readResponse()` function accepts three arguments:`response`, `url` and `params`, but `fetch` only passes 1 argument: `response` causing `url` to be `undefined`.

#### Solution:

Pass three arguments to the `readResponse`

#### Snippet:

```
return readResponse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params), url, params);
```